# What is the complexity of policy gradient algorithms compared to discrete action space algorithms?

Tags: neural-networks, comparison, q-learning, policy-gradients, time-complexity

I am using a policy gradient algorithm (actor-critic) for wireless networks. The policy gradient-based algorithm helps because it considers continuous action space.

But how much does a policy gradient-based algorithm contribute to the complexity of the involved neural networks, compared to discrete action space algorithms (like Q-learning)? Moreover, in terms of computation, how do policy gradient algorithms (for continuous action spaces) compare to discrete action space algorithms?

Comment: Hi and welcome to this community! Can you please clarify what you mean by "system complexity"?

Comment: What do you mean by "I am using a policy gradient algorithm for wireless networks". Can you clarify exactly how you're using the policy gradient algorithms in the context of wireless networks?